# Extend my Ubuntu dual boot partion

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

i have a dual-boot laptop with both Windows 7 and Ubuntu 16.04.

Currently, the Windows side has too much disk space, and I want to resize things so that the Ubuntu side has more.

I have actually 100Gb unallocated space got from the D partition, and i want to add to my Ubuntu partition, like shown in the picture below, the problem is that Ubuntu partition and it's Swap part are in the middle of my Windows partitions:

[image: My laptop Partitions]

Can I expand the Linux partition from Windows or do I need to be in Ubuntu or do I need to create a boot disk and do it that way?

Or do I need third party software?

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu

Comment: no, it's not duplicate.

Comment: @heynnema the OP is always notified when a new answer is posted. There's no need to let them know with a comment.

Comment: @terdon I know. Thanks. However, when I see a rep of 1, it's mostly a training exercise to remind them to accept the answer if it was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy...

**Note**: Your NTFS partitions for your C:, D:, and E: are full. F: is fine. Consider backing up and deleting some stuff to make more room.

## Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or loose data.

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a `swapoff` on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a `swapon` on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower pane of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted`
- **move** /dev/sda4 all the way left # **Since you didn't show us a gparted screenshot, check that this is the correct partition number for the Ubuntu ext4 partition**
- **resize** /dev/sda4 all the way to the right
- click the Apply button
- reboot

Comment: Thank you, but is this method may alter my windows or Ubuntu data

Comment: @Katty  As long as I've guessed the correct partition number, it certainly won't touch your Windows partitions, and your Ubuntu data should be intact, unless something goes wrong during the procedure... that's why I recommend having a good backup of your important Ubuntu files first. Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: My important files are in the Windows system, so as you say they will not affected

Comment: @Katty correct... this procedure only manipulates the Ubuntu partition. When you start `gparted`, just assure that /dev/sda4 is correct for your Ubuntu ext4 partition. But... it's always a good idea to have good backups of your important Windows files too.

Comment: @Katty let me know how you do, ok?

Answer (score 2):

The general rule is to use Windows to change the Windows partitions, and Ubuntu to change the Ubuntu partitions.

In this specific case, you are altering your root partition, and this cannot be done while that partition is active.  You will need to boot from a live USB, and run `gparted` from that USB to change the ext4 partition that you have for Linux.

Since the 33 GB linux partition is contiguous with a 100 GB unallocated space, you can expand the 33 GB partition to include some or all of that unallocated space.

Comment: but the problem is the unaalocated spce is in the left of my ext4 and it should be in the right to expand my Ubuntu partition.

Comment: Gparted can handle this by either extending to the left, or moving the partition to the left first, and then extending to the right.

Comment: can you give me a video that explain this, thank you.

Comment: There are many on youtube.  [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SALU-jmUiuc](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SALU-jmUiuc) is one example.

Comment: @Katty Video tutorials are off-topic here...